# How can I trace wires from a ceiling box to find the power source?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a dead wire in ceiling box. I've looked at all boxes in walls around the area and found no problems. Breakers are good. How can I trace that wire and find where it is tied into? I don't have attic access at all so that is my problem.

Comment: Some electricians use a tool Greenlee CS8000 to find broken or shorted wires. these are a bit expensive for the home owner. Just last week I was tracing a branch circuit that went several different directions found the open through conduit with this tool, a splice came apart in a box. the other way is hand over hand. trace the wire looking close at every staple point for damage or any kind of melting of the insulation. where you have access to the wires other than having someone trace it with a through the wall scanner that is your best hope since you have checked the boxes & breakers.

Comment: Tools like the Extech CB10 are are a lot cheaper, no idea if they are any good for tracing through intermediate boxes though.

Comment: @EdBeal - Does that CS8000 allow you to trace individual conductors or does the excitation signal couple into all wires in a bundle?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick - I have used two different products very similar to the CB10 (and also in that same price category) and found performance far from stellar. I would be hard pressed to try yet another in that same category.

Comment: The signal is put on a hot and a ground or neutral then you can follow the signal until it drops off and you will be within a few inches of the location depending on a short or open. I have found outlets that were covered over and the stabs had failed so none of the outlets after that one worked. I was the 3 or 4th electrician they called and I found the problem in less than 15 minutes total time. 1 electrician charged them a full day and did not find the problem. So you might ask if hiring an electrician if they have a scanner that can read through walls.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick, the cb10 is a circuit breaker finder these are not so good at tracing through walls. the other problem is if the circuit is on L1 every outlet and light in the house on L1 now has the tone and these are sketchy at best for finding breakers although I do use them on occasion instead of the 8000. the 8000 can read through plaster with steel lath. I have never found another scanner that works this well. both for finding breakers and for opens and shorts.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to trace every wire in my house to figure out what the heck was going on with my kitchen and dining room circuits.

For the purpose I ended up buying Sperry's Wire Tracker. I think I paid about $50 for it. It has a base unit and a pen. The base unit has two alligator clips that you clip on to a wire you are tracing. It works best if you are tracing two wires that go to the same place for reasons I will detail in a second, but you can clip just one clip to one wire if necessary. Turn off the power, obviously.

Turn on the base unit, then hold down the button on the pen. The base unit uses the wires as an antenna for a radio signal which the pen receives. It will beep if the pen is close to a wire in the same circuit, though the signal attenuates strongly at each junction. It is strong enough to penetrate drywall, but I had the best luck by pointing it at various fictures and switches. You will get a lot of false positives, though, as other wires will resonate with the signal. When you have a candidate wire, touch the metal tip of the pen to the bare wnd of the wire. If it really is on the circuit, the beeping will get louder and clearer. If it's not, it will get staticky.

Remember where I said it's best if you can clip two wires? If you clip, say, the hot and neutral, and then you are at the next branch on that circuit so that you are looking at the other end of both wires, when you touch the two wires together the signal will stop entirely. This is a great positive affirmation that you have the right wires.

Edit: [Here's an Amazon link. About $40.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00279JLBQ)

Comment: OP issue is broken or dead wires. I believe your tool only works on working wires.

Answer (score 0):

AC: If you have a decent voltmeter, you can hook an inductor (coil) between the leads, set the meter to millivolts AC and wave the inductor in the general direction of the wires you're concerned with. If they're hot, you'll pick up a little voltage. With 117AC this'll work over a distance of several inches. I've used inductors in the range of a milliHenry or so for this purpose. The circuit is not picky, you're just making an air-gap transformer.

Comment: Since we are shooting from the hip on this one a AM radio picks up 60hz well if not tuned to a station... but you would be chasing every live wire in the house with this as the coil idea